# How to set yesterday's date using Scala?

Tags: scala, date, simpledateformat

I am creating a date in Scala.

```
  val dafo = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'")
  val tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
  dafo.setTimeZone(tz)
  val endTime = dafo.format(new Date())
```

How can I set the yesterday's date instead of today's date?

Comment: Do you have any *really good* reasons not to use the new (shiny, and *sane*) [JSR-310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) implementation in `java.time` instead? I mean, `java.util.Date`...? I can't think of any other software package that tried so hard to murder me in the most painful way. Maybe it's just my subjective perception, I don't know... [Still using java.util.Date? Don't!](https://programminghints.com/2017/05/still-using-java-util-date-dont/)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: So, how my example would look using JSR-310 implementation?

Comment: Do you just want yesterdays *date*? In your own time zone? Any particular time of day? Same time yesterday? `java.time` can give you it all, so please make your pick. Or just follow [the Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Example: `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/Martinique")).minusDays(1)`

Comment: @OleV.V. Maybe it should be emphasized that this is an example of using `minusDays` in `java.time`, not an example of printing `UTC` time in the format requested by the OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how you get yesterday's date/time and format it using `java.time`:

```
import java.time.{ZonedDateTime, ZoneId}
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter


val yesterday = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")).minusDays(1)
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'")
val result = formatter format yesterday

println(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Calendar:

```
val dafo = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'")
val tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
dafo.setTimeZone(tz)

val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)
dafo.format(calendar.getTime)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate regarding the JSR-310 implementation mentioned in the comments?

Comment: import java.util.Calendar

Answer (score 4):

JSR-310 implementation:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(OffsetDateTime.now().minusDays(1L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternate solution. I think its a cleaner version.

```
val today = java.time.LocalDate.now

today: java.time.LocalDate = 2019-12-10

val yesterday= java.time.LocalDate.now.minusDays(1)

yesterday: java.time.LocalDate = 2019-12-09
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. Added some context